# prometheus percentage by label

Tags: prometheus, micrometer

i'm trying to get percentage of failure from under metric

```
function_counter_total{name="getCar", status="fail"}
function_counter_total{name="getCar", status="emit"}
```

using prometheus query `function_counter_total{status="fail"} / function_counter_total{status="emit"}` buy return 'No datapoints found'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a recommended way to exporter a metric as a) it's more difficult to work with in PromQL and b) labels should be partitions over the space (presuming that emit is a superset of fail, if not then the calculation you're asking to perform is probably not what you want). Separate `function_total` and `function_failed_total` counters would be better.

If you have to work with metrics in this form you can do

```
     function_counter_total{status="fail"} 
   / ignoring(status)
     function_counter_total{status="emit"}
```